# Response.Redirect to same page with query string causes Postback issues in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, web, postback

I have spent the better part of today trying to figure this out and I am beside myself so any insights would be much appreciated. I have  a Web User Control ( we use them instead of the typical web forms throughout our app) that has 4 controls on it. A RadioButtonList, a button ,a checkboxlist and a DataGrid. The controls as such are not important but I'm just mentioning them here for context. The grid is the typical one that will display results based on selections made via the controls mentioned.

Everything worked as expected until I had to make a change where I had to use Response.Redirect to the same page with a query string so that the grid would display results based on the query string passed in. What I'm noticing is that on this redirected page, upon postback, I am unable to obtain values of the controls. So for example, when I select a value in the RadioButtonList ( autopostback is set to true) , the PageLoad is fired, but the value tat triggered the change is unavailable within Page_Load - instead the previous value is shown. Everytime, I select a different value in teh RadioBUttonList, Page_Load displays not the current value ( the value that caused a PostBack) but the previous one.

What am I doing wrong? Is this even possible..I have debugged al day and find everythign to work fine except for this problem. The orignal page ( the one from which the redirect is done) exhibits none of this. Please help me understand what's going on..

Adding code sample as requested.

```
public partial class ParentPage :     
{
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            labelMessage.Text = "";
            if (Page.IsPostBack == false)
            {
                //Initialize Page
                InitializePage();

                //Read query string and initialize page
                Hashtable queryparms = HttpQueryString.Decrypt(Request.Url.ToString());
                if (queryparms["OptionsChartType"] != null)
                {
                    string[] strChartType = queryparms["OptionsChartType"].ToString().Split(',');
                    foreach ( string s in strChartType)
                    {
                        chkboxChartType.Items.FindByValue(s).Selected = true;
                    }
                }

                if (queryparms["OptionsRblBiasOptions"] != null) 
                    rblBiasOptions.SelectedValue = queryparms["OptionsRblBiasOptions"].ToString();
                if (queryparms["OptionsChartStyle"] != null)
                    rblChartStyle.SelectedValue = queryparms["OptionsChartStyle"].ToString();

                if (queryparms["OptionsDisplay"] != null) 
                {
                    string[] strDisplayOptions = queryparms["OptionsDisplay"].ToString().Split(',');
                    foreach ( string s in strDisplayOptions )
                    {
                        chkboxDisplay.Items.FindByValue(s).Selected = true;
                    }
                }

                if( queryparms.Count > 1)
                    BindGrid();
            }
            else
            {
                //Require this for sorting to work
                string abc = rblChartStyle.SelectedValue;
                BindGrid();
            }
        }
}

//Method that calls the Response.redirect
private void DisplayDetails()
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("~/MyContainer.aspx?ctrlPath=ParentPage.ascx");
        sb.Append("&OptionsChartType=" + CollectionToString(chkboxChartType.Items));
        sb.Append("&OptionsRblBiasOptions=Subject");
        sb.Append("&OptionsChartStyle=" + rblChartStyle.SelectedValue);
        sb.Append("&OptionsDisplay=" + CollectionToString(chkboxDisplay.Items));
        SaveUrl();
        Response.Redirect(HttpQueryString.Encrypt(sb.ToString()),false);
        this.Context.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
    }
```

You will see in the code above that the DisplayDetails method redirects to ParentPage itself with a query string. The redirect works fine as is but once we arrive at teh redirected page, any subsequent activity on the RadioButtonList etc that causes a postback does not have the change reflected in teh Page_Load. So, if I change the selected value of a RadioButtonList from "A" to "B", the string "abc" in the PageLoad method still has value "A". If I change "B" back to "A", string "abc" now has "A", which is the previous value.

Comment: show some code that u have tried as it is difficult to tell u what's wrong with code

Comment: Added code as requested above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got no responses for this. I have since modified my code to make use of ViewState as opposed to redirecting to the same page and everything works as needed. Still was hoping to learn something new. Thanks to all who viewed this thread.

Answer (score 0):

if you have to change the results on your GridView based on the UI controls value

- you should change the "DataSource" Propery of the GridView using the events on your UI
- check the "EnableViewState" of your controls

If not, please explain when you want to refresh your GridView

Thank you

Comment: Hopefully the code additions above will clarify my predicament